# Is there an easy way to make Spanish-language versions of all the graphs I've created?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a program that creates a bunch of bar graphs based on some data, with graph labels in English, but I've just been informed that I need to make two graphs for each metric: one with English labels and one with Spanish labels. Is there a neat way of doing this that doesn't involve repeating all my code with Spanish labels?

For example, how would I translate the labels in this plot:

```
plot(mtcars[,1:2], main = "Motor Trend Road Tests")
```

[image: screenshot]

or the similar plot in `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=cyl)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggtitle("Motor Trend Road Tests")
```

I need to translate column labels `cyl` and `mpg` and the title `Motor Trend Road Tests` into Spanish equivalents.

Clarification:  Let's assume that I know the translations, e.g. I want `mpg` to display as `Millas por galón`, etc.  How should I organize the code to make the substitutions easy?

Comment: Where do you expect to get Spanish translations from? Have you written them already and just need to make two sets of plots, or are you trying to find a translation service like Google? Those tend to not be that reliable

Comment: @camille:  I added some clarification.  Not my question, but I'm interested in seeing answers.

Comment: Some programming languages have ways to incorporate multiple translations seamlessly. I'm not sure there is such a thing in R, however, it should be relatively easy to emulate: replace labels with key-based references to an R environment containing the correct translation (an environment is like a hashtable). Change the environment to change the translation. For instance replace `"Motor Trend Road Test"` with `strings$motor_trend_title`, where `strings` is the environment and `motor_trend_title` for which the value is the original character string (or a translation).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut:  R has `gettext()` to do things like this, but it's not trivial to set up.  Probably the OP would be best to use some version of your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on @Jean-ClaudeArbaut's comment, and inspired by the `gettext()` function in R.

Write a small function to handle translations, and use it in place of explicit strings wherever you have a translatable message.  Have a global variable to select a language.  For example,

```r
msg <- function(s) {
  translation <- NA
  if (Language == "English") {
    translation <- c(
      "cyl" = "Cylinders",
      "mpg" = "Miles per gallon"
    )[s]
  } else if (Language == "Spanish") {
    translation <- c(
      "cyl" = "Cilindros",
      "mpg" = "Millas por galón",
      "Motor Trend Road Tests" = "Pruebas de carretera de Motor Trend"
    )[s]
  }
  if (is.na(translation)) s else translation
}

library(ggplot2)

Language <- "Spanish"
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=cyl)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggtitle(msg("Motor Trend Road Tests")) +
  xlab(msg("mpg")) +
  ylab(msg("cyl"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

In the function, I list all the translations I have prepared.  If you enter a string that hasn't been translated, it will be left as-is. That way you only need to enter "translations" into English for the variable names, not for the title.  (Apologies if my translations aren't the best:  I'm not a Spanish speaker!)

It would be nice if there was a way to make the automatically generated labels (like `mpg`) be automatically translated, but I don't know one,
so I had to repeat them in `xlab()` and `ylab()` calls.

Edited to add:  In fact, `ggplot2` objects are quite structured, so automatic translation should be possible.  For example,

```
g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=cyl)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggtitle("Motor Trend Road Tests")
```

creates an object `g` which contains `g$labels` holding all the labels that need translation.  It should be possible to write a function that automatically finds and translates those labels.